# php DOMDocument()->getAttribute() not working

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I want to get the value of `href` attribute of `a` tag from HTML inside a string.

I have made a PHP fiddle [here](https://ideone.com/hGsrDZ) because the `string` is too long.

Error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'undefined' (T_STRING) in...
```

Comment: It seemingly does work.. I get the href in ```$url``` when I run your code in [the php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com)

Comment: The first message I get is `<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : a in Entity`. Your `<a>` tag is missing the starting `<`.

Comment: That string is incorrect, the actual one is very long. Can you please take a look at this - https://ideone.com/hGsrDZ I am getting an error.

Comment: You should use a heredoc or nowdoc to define your string

Comment: You should place relevant code in the question itself. Furthermore, the linked code triggers `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'undefined' (T_STRING)` :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php Sandbox your code works.

However, you forgot `<` at the beginning of `a` tag.

```
<?php
$string = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
            <head>
            </head>
            <body onclick="on_body_click()" text="#000000" alink="#FF0000" link="#0000FF" vlink="#800080"> 
             <a href="/cgi-bin/new_get_recorded.cgi?l_doc_ref_no=7506389&amp;COUNTY=san francisco&amp;YEARSEGMENT=current&amp;SEARCH_TYPE=DETAIL_N" title="Document Details">Show Name Detail</a> 
                </body>
    </html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = $selector->query('//a[@title="Document Details"]');
$url = $result[0]->getAttribute('href');
echo $url;
```

In `$url` you have the `href` value (printed out).

It seems you have problem with the string and use of `'` and `"`.

If you start the `$string`  with `'` you cannot use it inside. You can use `'` just at the end to close the php variable `';`;

You have three solutions:

1. substitute `'` with `"` inside the string representing your html;
2. Use `\'` instead of only `'` inside the string representing your html. This tells to php that the string is not finished yet but that `'` represents the string content;
3. heredoc syntax;

For example with the first approach we have:

`$string = ' Inside the string you should use just this type of apostrophe "    ';`

Comment: That string is incorrect, the actual one is very long. Can you please take a look at this - https://ideone.com/hGsrDZ I am getting an error.

Comment: You have problem with the string. You misuse `'` and `"`

Answer (score 0):

For long multi-line strings, I prefer to switch to [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax which provide a more clean/visible way to handle strings and quotes within it. It also offers a "**WYSIWYG** display" of string as it is safe to insert line-breaks, tabs, spaces, quotes and double-quotes.

I switched your example to a HEREDOC syntax, and it run fine (with the correct result), except few warnings due to your malformed HTML input.

```
<?php

$string = <<<HTMLINPUT
Your multi-line HTML input goes here.
HTMLINPUT;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = $selector->query('//a[@title="Document Details"]');
echo $url = $result[0]->getAttribute('href');
```

Full example in a [separate fiddle](https://ideone.com/I3740b).

Hope it helps.